# Define isUnder method who compare to another Point

Tags: java, methods

i have class point:

```
public class Point
{
    private double _x;
    private double _y;

}
```

also i have `getX()`, `getY()` methods.
i need to define 2 methods:

```
1. public boolean isAbove(Point other)
2. public boolean isUnder(Point other)
```

So this is what I have come up with:

```
public boolean isAbove(Point other)
{
    if (this._y <= other._y)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean isUnder(Point other)
{   

}
```

I have tried several things on `isUnder` and get different results. What is the correct way to write those 2 methods ?

** important **

I have to use `isAbove()` method on `isUnder()` !!

Comment: Why is `isAbove` defined as "same height or above"? The method name is misleading. If you change the `isAbove`method to do what it says, it should work.

Comment: can you show me the best way the solve it ?

Comment: Did someone provide a sufficient answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isUnder` can be implemented like this

```
public boolean isUnder(Point other)
{   
     return (this._y != other.getY()) && !isAbove(other);
}
```

and `isAbove` can be

```
public boolean isUnder(Point other)
    {   
         return (this._y > other.getY());
    }
```

Comment: my instructions says (homework) that i need to use only isAbove method in order to write isUnder, do you think that yours answer is OK ?

Comment: Yes. My answer takes care if the point is in the same level. If the point is in the same level, it will give false in both `isUnder` and `isAbove`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with only 2 possibilities then isUnder = !isAbove so all you have to do is to do:

```
return !isAbove(other)
```

However, it seems to me that two points can be at the same level. Having said that I don't know the context so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a getter for your class if you want to be able to get it's value. Then use that method with your compare method:

```
public class Point
{
    private double _x;
    private double _y;

public double getY() {
return _y;
   }
public boolean isAbove(Point other)
{
    if (getY() <= other.getY())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i have getX() and getY(), and how to implement the isUnder ?

Comment: Then you need to use that method. You will not get the "other" value by calling other._y since it's a private variable, you must use getY() like stated in my post. To implement the isUnder is not that difficult since it's the opposite of isAbove. So either do same implementation but change the <, or do if(isAbove(other)=false) then isUnder() must be true. Altho isAbove will return false if two points have the same value as it's implemented now

Comment: Within the same class you have access to the private variables. No need to use getters there.

Comment: You can get this._y but not other._y. You will need a getter for other._y

Comment: @JimmyGustafsson: No, try it out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the number of methods and "isAbove" actually means "isAtSameHeightOrAbove"

```
public boolean isAbove(Point other)
{
    return this._y >= other._y;
}

public boolean isUnder(Point other)
{   
    return this._y != other._y && !isAbove(other);
}
```

Comment: see my update (i have to use isAbove method on isUnder) and cannot add another methods (this is my homework)